# Best way to fetch Rails ActiveJob results to return as JSON in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rails-activejob

I am building a web service that accepts a string, parses it and returns it as JSON. In my controller, I am calling an ActiveJob to run a service to parse the data. I would like to return the results of the ActiveJob back to my controller in order to return it as JSON and I am not sure how to do it. What is the simplest way to do this?

```
class GeocoderService
  require 'ruby_postal/parser'

  def initialize(address)
    @address = address
  end

  def parse_address
    address_group = {}
    result = Postal::Parser.parse_address(@address)
    result.each do |r|
      address_group[r.values[0]] = r.values[1]
    end
    address_group
  end

class ParseAddressJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(address)
    geo = GeocoderService.new(address)
    result = geo.parse_address
  end

end

class LocationsController < ApplicationController



def create
    if geo_params[:address]
      ParseAddressJob.perform_later(geo_params[:address])
      render json: result
    else
      render json: { error: "Invalid address"}, status: 400
    end
  end

  private

  def geo_params
    params.require(:geo).permit(:address)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

ActiveJob is used to create tasks that run in the background, and asynchronously from the HTTP request/response flow. The controller hands off the task to ActiveJob then the controller returns while the job runs in the future. If you need the output from a job immediately because its something the user needs then you shouldn't be using a job - you should just be calling the code the job calls directly and blocking until the code is finished so you can get the output.

```
def create
  if geo_params[:address]
    geo = GeocoderService.new(geo_params[:address])
    result = geo.parse_address
    render json: result
  else
    render json: { error: "Invalid address"}, status: 400
  end
end
```

If you're really concerned with the blocking that your controller action will do while it waits on the response from the geolocation API, you can institute a queueing system of your own, for your API consumers. The flow looks something like this:

1. A user makes a request to your endpoint
2. Your endpoint inserts a record in to a database table called GeoResults with a status of 'processing', and an empty response text. Get the ID of this record.
3. Your endpoint fires off the job as you're doing now, but now you also pass in the ID of the GeoResults record you created.
4. Your endpoint gives the user a URL to check this record in GeoResults.
5. Your consumer starts to poll this endpoint until they see the status of 'complete'
6. When your background job is completed, it updates its record in GeoResults (since it has the ID) with a status of 'complete', and assigns the geolocation response text.
7. Your consumer sees the update, and grabs the response.

Comment: Right, that was the code I had before but this service needs to handle a large volume of requests so I thought handling it off to a job would be best. Would you know of another way to scale it without using background jobs?

Comment: Firstly - do you have separate job workers from your rails web layer? If not, then the CPU cycles you're spending are the same as they would be in the code without ActiveJob. Even if your workers were separate, the time it takes will not be much different, if the bottleneck is the API. If it takes 6000 ms to run on your web layer, it will take 6000 ms to run in a worker, and since you have to wait on that response to give it to the user, you're still not in a better place. I'm editing the post to add a suggestion for a way to do what you're asking.